# Include live remote image in Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, media9, javascript

From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214092/hyperref-package-including-web-image-in-pdf-document), I see that it is possible to include remote images within a PDF, via the `media9` package. Can direct inclusion of Javascript--as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3080/what-is-the-best-way-to-insert-document-level-javascript-in-latex-documents)--be used to update the image (technically, the swf object) at a specified interval?

Comment: I'll try and write a dedicated slideshow App for inclusion with `media9`. May take a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version `[2015-05-11]` of `media9` provides [`SlideShow.swf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/players/SlideShow.swf) which is an image gallery app for live and static remote (downloaded at viewing time) and static embedded image files in the PNG, JPEG and GIF formats. `SlideShow.swf` is configured via an [XML file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/files/config.xml) with very simple syntax.

The app can be interacted with using the right-click menu or the keyboard.

The link which follows is the slide-show example embedded in the `media9` documentation file, opened in the web browser. (The fourth image doesn't work here because it uses a URL which is relative to the player SWF file):

http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/players/SlideShow.swf?xml=../doc/files/config.xml

A minimal beamer-class example of a single-image "slide-show" using the remote live image URL given in the OP would read:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Live remote image}
  \includemedia[
    width=\linewidth,
    height=0.46\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,
    passcontext, %show context menu
    addresource=show.xml,
    flashvars={ xml=show.xml }
  ]{}{SlideShow.swf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with file `show.xml` containing the lines:

```xml
<SlideShow>
  <Img live="3">
    <caption>Live remote image.</caption>
    <URL>http://dev.eightbeers.org/tex/corner-icon.png</URL>
  </Img>
</SlideShow>
```

The remote image will be refreshed every three seconds.

Comment: Works like a charm! I hope you enjoyed the test png :)

Comment: This is a tiny detail, but is it possible to remove the quarter-watch "loading" icon in the top-left of the graphic?

Comment: @kyle: Providing some kind of loading feedback isn't that bad an idea, I believe. It should move out of view when the mouse is moved out of the image display.

Comment: @kyle: Would you mind making permanent the URL of the maw-the-lawn simulation? It is a great example of demonstrating live image display (I don't know of a better one).

Comment: @kyle: Ok, in the next version the cursor will be explicitly hidden when the mouse is moved out.

Comment: I agree that it's good usability to have it. I just realized this morning that the loading icon doesn't render when the mouse is moved out, so I think you built in a nice compromise.

Comment: The URL won't change, the server says "dev" but really it's a playground. If you want a permanent-looking URL, use this: http://1.618034.com/corner-icon.png

Comment: @kyle :  There seems to be something wrong  with http://1.618034.com/corner-icon.png . Would you please have a look at it?

Comment: it doesn't work the same as it used to (code is ancient and hasn't changed, so this is weird) but the URL still loads a valid PNG on my mobile browser. What kind of problem are you noticing?

Comment: The mower doesn't draw contiguous trails , but jumps between four positions aligned in a cross.

Comment: Fixed. Issue was an upgrade to a new DB engine and an introduced SQL typo. This code is only used for this answer so it doesn't get a lot of testing.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56849/insert-web-content-dynamically-javascript?rq=1) has a pretty solid answer. There are still issues with what happens when the object reloads (the entire graphic goes black while Reader fetches the content); anyone who has a suggestion for that, I'd be happy to hear.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}                                                                                                    
    \begin{frame}{Test auto-updated input}{}
        \includemedia[                                                                                                      
            height=5cm,
            label=sample,
            width=11cm,
            activate=pageopen,
            flashvars={
                src=http://dev.eightbeers.org/tex/corner-icon.png
                &controlBarMode=none
            },
        ]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}% I'll be honest, not too sure about indentation in the following
\pdfannot width 0pt height 0pt depth 0pt {                                                                          
    /Subtype/Widget                                                                                                   
    /AA <</PO <<  %start updating routine on 'pageopen' event                                                                                                      
        /S/JavaScript/JS (                                                                                              
            try{var ret=app.setInterval('                                                                                 
                annotRM["sample"].activated=false;                                                                          
                annotRM["sample"].activated=true;                                                                           
            ' , 2500);}catch(e){}
        )
    >>>>
}
    \end{frame}                                                                                                         
\end{document}
```

**If you have issues loading your own dynamic images:**

- `StrobeMediaPlayback.swf` will only load images if it recognizes the file suffix; so if you are building dynamic images in PHP you will need to use some `.htaccess`-fu to redirect from a `.jpg` or `.png` or the like
- While most browsers play nicely when an image is sent without a `Content-Length:` header, `StrobeMediaPlayback.swf` will fail with the cryptic `Argument Error - Invalid parameter passed to method`