# How do I include a local GIF image into beamer using media9 package

Tags: media9

From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233886/include-live-remote-image-in-beamer-presentation), there is a way to include images with a hyperlink using the media9 package included in TeXLive. I am trying to include a GIF image (supported directly by the media9 package) in a beamer slide:

```
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Motivation from photography}
            \includemedia[
            width=0.3\linewidth,keepaspectratio,
            activate=onclick,
            %addresource=config.xml, %embedded configuration
            addresource=../../../../Documents/Horse_galloping.gif, %embedded image file
            %flashvars={xml=config.xml},
            %passcontext %show the player’s context menu
            ]{}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
    \end{frame}
```

I still have some trouble: my tex file compiled successfully but when I opened the pdf file (adobe reader; Foxit doesn't show the gif image) and clicked on the window, it showed the following error: "we are unable to connect to the content you've requested. We apologize for the inconvenience" (TypeError - Error#1009). Some background: I compiled with pdflatex-biber-pdflatex-pdflatex sequence. I called the media9 package by

```
\usepackage{media9}
```

Comment: This not use `media9` package, but maybe works ...   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74073/gif-image-in-beamer-presentation

Comment: I checked the link out. I think it is a good option. However, I'd like to know a direct way of inserting a gif image. The method in the link is a longer piece of code I think. There gotta be a shorter way

Comment: If it is a single, to-be-embedded image file, why don't you convert the GIF to PNG and insert that using `\includegraphics` as usual? Is it animated GIF? Note that the `media9` based method relies on using the Flash Player plugin in Adobe Reader which doesn't support animated GIFs. Moreover your code cannot work. `StrobeMediaPlayback` isn't the right app, use `SlideShow.swf` as  in the answer you cited.

Comment: I think you are right about the app which should be SlideShow.swf. On the other hand, I am trying to insert an animated gif. I missed the fact that media9 doesn't support anjmated gifs. Do you have a suggestion on the package that might work?

Comment: @HuyNguyen the second response in link is relatively short to use gif in beamer

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to use GIF images with media9 as well without success. In the end, I was able to include the animation using an MP4 video instead. Turning a GIF into an MP4 is easy, you can use kdenlive for this. Once you have the MP4 file, you can include the animation as follows:

```latex
\begin{frame}
\includemedia[
    width=.3\linewidth,
    height=.3\linewidth,
    addresource=../../../../Documents/Horse_galloping.gif,
    transparent,
    activate=pageopen,
    passcontext,
    flashvars={
        source=../../../../Documents/Horse_galloping.gif
        &loop=true
    }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}
```

Not the best solution, but it works. On the bright side, the MP4 file uses less space than the actual GIF, which is a plus.